# How to do SVD of the diﬀerentiation operator of $P_{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Find the singular values of the differentiation operator $D \colon P_{2}  \rightarrow P_{2}$ where $P_{2}$ is the vector space of real polynomials of degree less than or equal to $2$, and the inner product on $P_{2}$ is given by

$$ \left<f,g \right> :=\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)g(t) \,dt. $$

Using the brute-force method, I cannot even find the adjoint of this map.

I have just came up with the idea that the only eigenvalue of the differential operator is $0$, as the conjugation of $0$, $0$ is the only eigenvalue of the $D^*$. But I cannot say anything about the composition $D^{*}D$...

So could someone provide some ideas of solving this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with finding an orthonormal basis for $P_2$ by applying Gram-Schmidt to the standard basis $(1,x,x^2)$. Using the fact that the integral of an odd function on $[-1,1]$ vanishes, we get:

$$ e_1 = \frac{1}{\|1\|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \\
e_2 = \frac{x - \left< x, e_1 \right> e_1}{x - \left< x, e_1 \right> e_1} = \frac{x}{\|x\|} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} x, \\
e_3 = \frac{x^2 - \left< x^2, e_2 \right> e_2 - \left< x^2, e_1 \right> e_1}{\|x^2 - \left< x^2, e_2 \right> e_2 - \left< x^2, e_1 \right> e_1\|} = \frac{x^2 - \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 x^2 \, dx}{\| x^2 - \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 x^2 \, dx \|} = \frac{x^2 - \frac{1}{3}}{\| x^2 - \frac{1}{3} \|} = \sqrt{\frac{45}{8}} \left( x^2 - \frac{1}{3} \right).$$

Then, we calculate:

$$
D(e_1) = 0,\\
D(e_2) = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} = \sqrt{3} e_1, \\
D(e_3) = \sqrt{\frac{45}{2}}x = \sqrt{15} e_2.
$$

From here, since the $e_i$ are orthonormal, we already see that the singular values of $D$ are $\sqrt{15}, \sqrt{3}, 0$. Alternatively, we can see that with respect to $\mathcal{B} = (e_1, e_2, e_3)$, the operator $D$ is represented by the matrix

$$ [D]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \sqrt{15} \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

and $D^{*}$ is represented by the transpose

$$ [D^{*}]_{\mathcal{B}} = [D]_{\mathcal{B}}^t = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{15} & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Hence,

$$ [D^{*}D]_{\mathcal{B}} = [D^{*}]_{\mathcal{B}} [D]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 15 \end{pmatrix} $$

which also shows that the eigenvaleus of $\sqrt{D^{*}D}$ which are the singular values of $D$ are $\sqrt{15}, \sqrt{3}, 0$.

Comment: May I ask, can this be done just using the standard basis? (Although since the inner product was mentioned, I would presume the orthonormal basis is intended.) Maybe you would also please address why the singular values, as eigenvalues of $\sqrt{T^*T}$ would be dependent on a particular basis, whereas eigenvalues of a linear operator are not. Thanks. With regards,

Comment: You can't talk about $T^{*}$ as an operator from $V$ to itself without introducing an inner product (because the defining property of $T^{*}$ is $\left< Tu, v \right> = \left< u, T^{*} v \right>$). The singular values of an operator $T$ are the non-negative roots of the eigenvalues of $T^{*}T$. The eigenvalues themselves do not depend on the basis with respect to which you represent $T^{*}T$ but the operator $T^{*}$ depends on the inner product. If you change the inner product, $T^{*}$ will change.

Comment: One way to compute $T^{*}$ is to represent $T$ with respect to an orthonormal basis of $(V, \left< \cdot, \cdot \right>)$ by a matrix $A$ and then $T^{*}$ is represented with respect to the same basis by $A^T$ and then you can proceed to compute the eigenvalues of $T^{*}T$ (which are the eigenvalues of $A^T A$). If you don't use an orthonormal basis, the matrix $A^T$ won't represent $T^{*}$.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough explanation.